# Translate web formular mouse click actions into curl commands

Tags: curl, scripting

I neet to fill some web formular, more than hundred of times, with different data and I thought about making a script and using curl for this. I am very new to this language, but I heard that it is possible to perform actions with the web browser so that it translates them directly to curl commands, do you know whether this is possible?

Comment: not a curl solution, but to me it seems that you'd be better off using something like http://simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html or even JMeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not very familiar with webformular, so this approach might not work. However, I've had to do something similar in the past, and I am going to describe how to do it.

**N.B.** This approach will work with basic forms that don't use https encryption and don't require authentication. You can definitely extend this script to work with more complex forms, but that it outside the scope of this answer.

Furthermore, if you're using this to automate a form that does **POST** requests, please be a little more careful than if you're just doing **GET** requests, because any bug in your script could lead to "more than hundred of times" of bad data being sent over.

1. Open the form in Chrome.
2. Find out what *action* the form uses. Right click the form in Chrome, > "Inspect element". You will see some text come up below. Look for something like this:

   <form name="who cares" method="POST" action="[this is important]">

Make a note of the text after action. That's what you'll need for a later step.

3. Fill in some example values into the form.

4. Start the Chrome Developer Tools. (For me, that is Control+Shift+I).

5. Go to the "Network" tab in the Chrome toolbox, and keep an eye on it.
6. Submit your form. Now, when you do, you should see some activity in the network tab. You need to figure out which call was created by submitting the form. This is why you remember the action back in step 2. Look for an entry that has a Path the same as the action of the form.
7. When you find it, right click that command and select "Copy as cURL". Voila, you now have a cURL command you can use!
8. Put that cURL command in a script, and then change the example values you filled in step 3 to the values you want to fill in automatically. For example, if the cURL command is:

   curl '[somewebsite]/[form action]' -H 'Origin: [somewebsite]' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'name=Danver&status=Awesome' --compressed

Leave the headers (the things passed by -H) alone, and look for the field --data. In it, change the values around, perhaps by using a script. Exact details on this will depend on your scripting language.

9. And now you're done, as long as your form doesn't require an active session cookie to submit forms. If that's the case, the approach you'll have to take is slightly outside the scope of this answer, but it's still possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Behat + Mink is more useful for that purpose. 
Take a look over here for example: http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/manipulating-pages.html#form-field-manipulations

In fact your actions will be translated to curl after all, but you will not have to dive into details, you'll be describing them in a very comfortable way...
And after that you can claim to be QA junior specialist :)

Behat documentation: http://behat.org

Nice tutorial video: http://lin-clark.com/blog/2013/11/26/quickstart-testing-with-behat-mink-selenium/